# Why maven is not finding a package located in another module/project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to compile a multi-module maven project. I have problems to compile a new module I added. This problem arises because the new module is trying to import a pair of packages which exist in another module.

This is the pom.xml of the new module:

[image]
[image]

Here is the view in the eclipse's project explorer, where i highlighted the 2 packages I'm importing from the class *ServicioJMS* of the new module:

[image]
[image]

And here's the error showed in the command line after doing a *mvn clean package*

[image]

As you can see below I added the module in the parent pom.xml:

[image]

So, I don't know what I'm doing wrong here ¿Any ideas?

**NOTE: Eclipse has no problem resolving the dependencies related to the discussed imports.**

Comment: I am not sure if that is just cropping issue but in case it is not pom.xml of your new module is invalid. There is dangling </dependency> and <dependencies> is missing... (PS: You should not post code as images...)

Comment: There're no dangling tags. I know posting the code as a codeblock is the best choice but I don't want to show too much information because I'm working with sensitive data.

Comment: The same problem might be because of spring-boot-plugin, or other plugin with the same functionality. So, you cannot depend on module with such plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1) Don't put a version or group if you have a parent, let them be picked up from the parent.

2) When importing a dependency from a module under the same parent use ${project.version}

here's an example:

```
   <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.essexboy</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>web</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.essexboy</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Understood, it's good to know but this isn't solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. Go to the library on which you are depending (under your ~/.m2/repository directory or in the ./target directory of the library) and find the compiled library jar. Use jar -tf to list it and check that the missing classes are listed directly in the jar.

If you are using the spring boot maven plugin or similar in the library on which you are depending then it constructs a jar with a radically different structure and the classes, while being in there, will be hidden within the structure rather than being directly in the jar by name. Eclipse understands this, but the spring boot loader won't unpack the spring boot maven plugin structure of a library within a dependency, it will only do that for the runnable jar being executed.

If this is true for you then you can remove the offending build plugin from the pom of your library making it just a library, not a runnable spring boot jar.

Comment: Many thanks. I was using spring-boot-maven-plugin within my dependency project and removing it helped me use it directly in the dependent project

Answer (score 0):

Use install instead of package because IntegradorTransformador artifact (jar) was created but not exists in m2 repository and IntegradorTransformadorReproceso project can't found the artifact

```
mvn clean install
```

Comment: @EdgarHernandez if you open the IntegradorTransformador  jar installed in m2, do it contains the package? looks like the artifact is empty, but not missing like I thought